# Not getting Id for a row while doing dynamic binding for Datatable using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

everything is binding fine. but when i click that icon its getting wrong value sometimes In result[i][10] on onclick function not able get id. can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
 success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                var result = response.map(function (item) {
                    var result = [];
                    // result.push(i++);
                    result.push(item.GunId)
                    result.push(item.BranchName);
                    result.push(item.GunSerialNo);
                    result.push(item.GunTypeName);
                    result.push(item.ModelNo);
                    result.push(item.CarriedBy);
                    result.push(item.Bullets);
                    result.push(item.Purpose);
                    result.push(item.IssueDate);
                    result.push(item.IssueTime);
                    result.push(item.EstimatedTime)

                    //result.push(item.a)

                    return result;
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    result[i][0] = "<span hidden='hidden'>" + result[i][0] + "</span>";                       
                    result[i][0] = "<span>" + result[i][1] + "</span>";
                    result[i][1] = "<span>" + result[i][2] + "</span>";
                    result[i][2] = "<span>" + result[i][3] + "</span>";
                    result[i][3] = "<span>" + result[i][4] + "</span>";
                    result[i][4] = "<span>" + result[i][5] + "</span>";
                    result[i][5] = "<span>" + result[i][6] + "</span>";
                    result[i][6] = "<span>" + result[i][7] + "</span>";
                    result[i][7] = "<span>" + result[i][8] + "</span>";
                    result[i][8] = "<span>" + result[i][9] + "</span>";
                    result[i][9] = "<span>" + result[i][10] + "</span>";
                    result[i][10] = "<button type='button' title='Remarks' class='btn btn-xs  btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#gun-tracking-remark-popup' onclick='OpenRemarks (result[i][0])' ><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></button>";

                    $("#GunTracking-detail-datatable").DataTable().row.add(result[i]);


                }
                $("#GunTracking-detail-datatable").DataTable().draw();
            }
```

Comment: No, sorry. There is not enough information here to answer your question. Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Yes i tried debugging my code. in result array id is not coming.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using DataTables 1.10.  If so you are really fighting against your library here.

So to start off you can define your "data -> column" mapping using the "columns" option when constructing your DataTable.  This way you don't have to build the map like you are doing.  Instead it will be able to just read your data set.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data

Next off you can use the "render" option in "columns" to define the "display" rendering for each data item.  That is where you can wrap stuff with your span elements for display but ommit them when sorting or filtering.  You can use a function here so you can reuse the same general function most of your columns.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Next if you need a lot of control over the return from the server in cases where you can't modify serverside code you can specify your own JQuery ajax function using the "ajax" option.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Lastly for your button click events you can wire them up after the datatable has been added to the page using a delegated click event like so:

```
var dataTable = $(dataTableSelector);
dataTable.on("click", "tbody tr td.buttonCellClass", function(evt) {
  // Do stuff;
});
```

I am on the tail end of ramping up on this library for a pretty complex serverside processing implementation.  Trust me that it is much easier working with the library than against it.

EDIT:  Forgot to mention that in "columnDefs" you can specify classes for your cells as well.

But if you just want the quick and dirty solution to your immediate issue.  I think the problem in your code is on this line:

```
result[i][10] = "<button type='button' title='Remarks' class='btn btn-xs  btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#gun-tracking-remark-popup' onclick='OpenRemarks (result[i][0])' ><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></button>";
```

You will want to change this part:

```
onclick='OpenRemarks(result[i][0])'
```

TO:

```
onclick='OpenRemarks(" + result[i][0] + ")'
```

You had your array accessor within the string literal

EDIT2: used single quote when I needed double quote.